# How to add items from Edittext to listview?

Tags: java, android

I have been striving for a couple of hours but I still can't figure out why my latest edittext value overwrites my old listview item.

The problem is that, suppose I type a string `s1` in my edittext and press the **add to listview** button, then the string `s1` gets entered successfully. Now if I type a string `s2` in my edittext and press the **add to listview** button, the string `s2` now replaces `s1` in the listview, and thus now it is just showing `s2` in my listview. How do I fix this?

*Here is my code:*

```
String str=edittext.getText().toString();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(My_activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                         if(str.length()!=0) {
                                list.add(str);
                               }

                   listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
});
```

**Edit:** I am trying to take the input string from one activity and trying to add it to the listview of another activity. This is where the problem arises. Please help me.

*1st Activity:*

```
public static String str;
add.setOnClickListener(new (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                             str=edittext.gettext().toString();
}
});
```

*2nd Activity:*

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(My_activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);

    if (Main_activity.i == R.id.event_1 || Main_activity.i == R.id.rem_1) {
     listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 if(str.length()!=0) {
                    list.add(str);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
    else{
     Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "No 
     text found", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
     snackbar.show();
    }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what the end goal is but it looks like you need to store the text somewhere, a database or maybe sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. I guess the adapter wasn't updating after getting a new item. So what I did was:

*1st Activity:*

```
 public static String str;
add.setOnClickListener(new (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                             str=edittext.gettext().toString();
                             list.add(s3);
}
});
```

*2nd Activity:*

```
  public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(My_activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (Main_activity.i == R.id.event_1 || Main_activity.i == R.id.rem_1) {
     listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 if(str.length()!=0) {
                    list.add(str);

                }
    else{
     Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "No 
     text found", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
     snackbar.show();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ListViewExample extends AppCompatActivity {

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView listView;
EditText editText;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
FloatingActionButton fab

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_view_example);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListViewExample.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            if(!name.isEmpty()) {
                list.add(name);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editText.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is my Activity, and this is work for me.

Comment: Tried it, not working; still facing the same problem

Comment: Will update the answer in a while. Will try it creating a new project

Comment: Check it out now, I have added my complete activity and this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above code is correct, please try to modularize your code. It will make your life easier when comes to debugging it and sequentially follow it. See below

```
private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private EditText editText;

@Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  initViews();
}

public void initViews() {
  editText = findViewById(R.id.et);
  Button addOptionsBtn = findViewById(R.id.button);
  addOptionsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
      addOptionToList();
    }
  });

  mAdapter =
      new ArrayAdapter<>(getBaseContext(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
        list);
 ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.options_list_view);
 listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private void addOptionToList() {
  String option = editText.getText().toString();
  if (option.isEmpty()) {
      return;
  }
  list.add(option);
  mAdapter.clear();
  mAdapter.addAll(list);
  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```